# Find matching elements between two arrays and update them

Tags: javascript, arrays

I think there is an easy solution but I've been working so long my brain is fried.

I have two arrays say for example:

```
[{name: "bob", age: 5},
 {name: "bob", age: 6}
 {name: "jim", age: 7}]
```

and an array I want to match against:

```
[{name: "bob", age: 5},
 {name: "bob", age: 6}]
```

I want to iterate through the first array and update all entries with `name: bob` to `age + 1`. So the resulting first array will be:

```
[{name: "bob", age: 6},
 {name: "bob", age: 7}
 {name: "jim", age: 7}]
```

I've tried a double for loop iterating through array1 then through array2 but the problem I get with that is I'll match `bob` twice, and in turn increment the age twice.

Comment: so if you find the name, you add 1 to their age?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO Yes, I've updated my question though. So for the second array I will see their name twice. And I do not want to increment each in the original array twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.map` to iterate through the `array1` and return the `modified` array.

Inside `Array.map`, find if the `current object` exists in `array2` using the `Array.find` method.
Update the `age` if object is found, other wise return the original array.

```js
var array1 = [{name: 'bob', age: 5},
 {name: 'bob', age: 6},
 {name: 'jim', age: 7}]


var array2 = [{name: 'bob', age: 5}, {name: 'bob', age: 6}]

var array3 = array1.map(arr => {
  if (array2.find(a => a.name === arr.name && a.age === arr.age)) {
    arr.age++;
  }
  return arr;
});

console.log(array3);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 const persons = [{name: "bob", age: 5}, {name: "bob", age: 6}, {name: "jim", age: 7}];

 const personsThatGotOlderToday = [{name: "bob" } /*...*/];

 for(const person of persons) {
   if(personsThatGotOlderToday.some(p => p.name === person.name)) 
     person.age++;
 }
```

However the array of people that got older should actually either just contain the persons name ... or it should be directly referencing the person objects, making the nested loop unneccessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` to loop through array and `.find` to find in the other array. If yes, increment the age else nothing

```js
var arr = [{name: "bob", age: 5},
 {name: "bob", age: 6},
 {name: "jim", age: 7}]
 
 var arr1 = [{name: "bob", age: 5},
 {name: "bob", age: 6}]
 
 arr.forEach(e=> arr1.find(a=> a.name === e.name) ? e.age++ :null)
 
 console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length(); i++)
  for (var j = 0; i < arr2.length(); j++)
    if (JSON.stringify(arr1[i]) === JSON.stringify(arr2[j])) {
      arr1[i].age += 1
```

might be some small syntax errors since I whipped this out quickly

Comment: I've updated my question, my second array was missing an extra element

Comment: updated answer. i believe the === will do a nested comparison

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array1 = [{"name": "bob", "age": 5},
 {"name": "bob", "age": 6},
 {"name": "jim", "age": 7}];
 
 var array2 = [{"name": "bob", "age": 5},{"name": "bob", "age": 6}]

 
var array3 = array1.map(val =>{val.age =  array2.filter(obj => obj.name == val.name).length>0? val.age +1 : val.age; return val;});

console.log(array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is es5 format works for me:

```js
    var arr = [{name: "bob", age: 5},{name: "bob", age: 6}, {name: "jim", age: 7}];
    for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i].name == "bob"){
            arr[i].age+=1;
        }
    }
    console.log(arr);
```